# source nat for return traffic (Hair pinning )

Tags: linux, iptables

Is there any way to source nat traffic received ?

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth18 --src 123.123.123.123/32 --jump SNAT --to-source 66.66.66.66
```

Return traffic still uses 123.123.123.123 as source (see timestamp 21:17:07.207832)

```
21:17:07.207786 IP 10.193.92.120 > 123.123.123.123: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 41622, length 40
21:17:07.207832 IP 123.123.123.123 > 10.193.92.120: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 41622, length 40

[root@Rats ~]# route -n | grep 10.193.88.0
10.193.88.0     10.193.88.1     255.255.248.0   UG    0      0        0 eth18
10.193.88.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 eth18
```

Here is how the RT looks like

```
[root@Rats ~]# ip route get 123.123.123.123
local 123.123.123.123 dev lo  src 123.123.123.123
    cache <local>  mtu 16436 advmss 16396 hoplimit 64
[root@Rats ~]# ip route get 10.193.92.120
10.193.92.120 via 10.193.88.1 dev eth18  src 10.193.92.126
    cache  mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64


[root@Rats ~]# route -n | grep 10.193.88.0
10.193.88.0     10.193.88.1     255.255.248.0 (<</21)   UG    0      0        0 eth18
10.193.88.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 eth18
```

I have attempted several things besides the IPtable command

```
for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter; do echo 0 > $f; done
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

but still no luck, any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inbound, local-destined packet is never going to go through the POSTROUTING chain of the NAT table:

[image: netfilter packet flow]
<sub>(https://www.garron.me/images/2012-04/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)</sub>

But Reading [The Fine Manual](http://man.he.net/man8/iptables) reveals:

> #### SNAT
>
> This target is only valid in the nat table, in the POSTROUTING and
> INPUT chains [...] 
> Kernels prior to 2.6.36-rc1 don't have the ability to SNAT in the INPUT chain.

So you should be using something along these lines:

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -i eth18 --src 123.123.123.123/32 -j SNAT --to-source 66.66.66.66
```

Note that this not only does change the chain to INPUT but also corrects the rule to use `eth18` as the *input* interface. You can verify if anything is hitting your rule by looking at the packet counters of `iptables -t nat -L INPUT -v -n`